# Wie nutze ich viel im Superlativ (am meisten) vor dem Nomen?

Tags: adjective-ending, superlativ

Wenn wir Superlativ vor einem Nomen verwenden, müssen wir die Adjektiv Deklination in der ende geben. z.B. Wir nehmen das schnellste Flugzeug.

Wie nutze ich Superlativ von viel (am meisten) vor einem Nomen - mit Adjektiv Deklination oder ohne?

z.B. Das ist das größte Schwimmbad mit den ---- (viel) Attraktionen hier.

Was ist korrekt - meisten oder meistenen (Typ 1 Dativ Plural)? Aber ich habe meistenen als wort im Wortschatz nicht gefunden.

Ist meisten eine Ausnahme, wenn wir das vor einem Nomen verwenden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Meisten" ist keine Ausnahme. Der Wortstamm ist *meist-*, so wie der Wortstamm bei "das schnellste" *schnellst-* ist:

> Wir nehmen das schnellste Flugzeug.
> Bauer Antons Kühe geben die meiste Milch.
> Müller Bergers Mühle mahlt das meiste Mehl.

> XYZ ist die größte Fluggesellschaft mit den schnellsten Flugzeugen.
> XYZ ist die größte Fluggesellschaft mit den meisten Flugzeugen.

Answer (score 0):

Die schwache Deklination von "meisten" im Plural ist in allen vier Fällen (N, A, G, D) dieselbe - nämlich "meisten".

Die Deklinationsform "meistenen" findest du in keinem Wörterbuch, weil sie nicht existiert.